# /clr option in c++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, clr, using-statement, directoryinfo

Can someone help me find a solution to the following error:

> "fatal error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option"

My configuration is ..

- Visual studio 2008
- Windows 7

Here is the code (i got by using net resources)

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

int main() {
    // Create a reference to the current directory.
    DirectoryInfo* di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment::CurrentDirectory);
    // Create an array representing the files in the current directory.
    FileInfo* fi[] = di->GetFiles();
    Console::WriteLine(S"The following files exist in the current directory:");
    // Print out the names of the files in the current directory.
    Collections::IEnumerator* myEnum = fi->GetEnumerator();
    while (myEnum->MoveNext()) {
        FileInfo* fiTemp = __try_cast<FileInfo*>(myEnum->Current);
        Console::WriteLine(fiTemp->Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the /clr option for the compiler already? Because that is basically what the error message tells you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k8d11d4s%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Just do what the error message suggests. It says that you have to enable the /clr option when using managed code, which is what you're doing. Either add the /clr switch to the compiler command line, or enable CLR (Common Language Runtime) support in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that mscorlib is automatically linked in, instead of you having to manually refer it.